# Grabbing specific query string parameters from URL with regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

We have an implementation of Liferay portal and I'm just getting started with using Google Analytics with it. I'm noticing a lot of duplicate entries in GA, mainly because of the query strings in the URI, for example:

```
/web/home-community/search-and-help?p_p_id=mytcdirectory_WAR_mytcdirectory&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-3&p_p_col_count=4&_mytcdirectory_WAR_mytcdirectory_action=getResults
```

I'm playing around with the Search and Replace filters in GA (using regex) and my goal is to try to pull out the `?p_p_id` and `&*_action` parameters from the URI, and disregard the rest. I'm getting close with the following regex:

```
^([^\?]+)([\?\&]p_p_id=[^\&]+)?.*(\&[^\&]+_action=[^\&]+)?.*$
```

But that last grouping isn't working correctly. If I remove the `?` from the end of the last grouping it matches, but the problem with that approach is that not all URIs contain that query string so it needs to be optional. But if I keep it in, it won't grab that last parameter. My regex fiddle is located here:

http://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/13

Thank you all in advance for any help.

Comment: I recommend that, instead of using a search/replace and cramming everything into a single regex you rather use several advanced filters in sequence. There is quite a good example under the filter box that shows how to re-order url parameters, you should be able to adapt this to your needs.